# Planning farm migration from SP2010 to SP2013: what should be the new hostname, web application and AAM?

Tags: migration, alternate-access-mapping, host-header

I am reviewing the plan to upgrade from SP2010 to SP2013. We apply Microsoft suggested approach:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

We setup a new SP2013 farm using similiar configuration with old farm. My question is, what should be the hostnames for new farm's machines? 
(Assume old machines hostname are SP-App, SP-Web01, SP-DB)

I believe the new machines setup should not use the same hostname as old farm. Because when new farm join the existing domain, conflict will occur.
(Assume new machines hostname are SP2013-App, SP2013-Web01, SP2013-DB)

In the existing application (old SP2010 farm), the AAM using are:

```
> Default Zone: http://SP-Web01

> Intranet Zone: http://SP-Web

> Internet Zone: http://SP.company.com

> the CA default zone: http://SP-Web01:5555
```

However, if we use new hostnames, what should be the new URL used for web application? What kind of AAM I should use? What should be the apply sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you cannot have two server with one in the same domain. In this case your AAM settings change according with your new server names.

New AAM

> `Default Zone: http://SP2013-Web01`
>
> `Intranet Zone: http://SP2013-Web`
>
> the CA default zone: `http://SP2013-Web01:5555`

Only thing is your Internet Zone URL (`Internet Zone: http://SP.company.com`), you have two options for this.

1. Either Change the DNS pointing to new SharePoint 2013 farm( Most probably your WEB server)
2. Or Create a new DNS which will point to new sharepoint 2013 farm,